# Unable to run heritrix job

Tags: heritrix

I am a new to Heritrix 3.1.1.
I got some error message when i run a job after startup Heritrix.

**My job configuration:**

metadata.operatorContactUrl="http://localhost"   
metadata.jobName=basic       
metadata.description=Basic crawl starting with useful defaults

**seeds.textSource.value** 

http://www.sina.com.cn

When I run the job on the console:
i get error message:

```
Exception in thread "myjob1 launchthread" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'CreateSymbolicLink
': ???????¨?
        at com.sun.jna.Function.<init>(Function.java:134)
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:345)
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:325)
        at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:203)
        at $Proxy6.CreateSymbolicLinkA(Unknown Source)
        at org.archive.util.FilesystemLinkMaker.makeSymbolicLink(FilesystemLinkMaker.java:94)
        at org.archive.spring.PathSharingContext.initLaunchDir(PathSharingContext.java:164)
        at org.archive.spring.PathSharingContext.start(PathSharingContext.java:114)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run a job using following command from commandline in linux environment.

```
curl -v -d "action=launch" -k -u admin:admin --anyauth --location     https://"localhost":8443/engine/job/myjob
```

You can refer [Heritrix API](https://webarchive.jira.com/wiki/display/Heritrix/Heritrix+3.x+API+Guide#Heritrix3.xAPIGuide-LaunchJob) from following page for further detalis.